# Does c++ chrono have a normal round function that rounds away from 0 on tie?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

`std::chrono::round` rounds to the nearest even number when it is exactly between numbers instead of rounding away from 0.

```
std::chrono::round<std::chrono::seconds>(3500ms) // = 4
std::chrono::round<std::chrono::seconds>(4500ms) // = 4 (instead of 5)
```

(Side question: Why would they do that?). I was wondering if their is a normal rounding function for chrono, like `std::round()`?

Comment: (Side answer: That's normal for rounding fairly instead of biasing toward rounding up. It's not specific to chrono.)

Comment: [`std::chrono::round`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/round) rounds towards nearest even number on a tie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practice, fair rounding is not very useful for engineering, graphics, DSP, etc...

You'll have to roll your own. Here is the standard rounding used in engineering. This will give you the most consistent rounding for engineering-related tasks.

```
auto rounded_to_nearest_s = std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(time + 500ms);
```

Keep in mind that rounding is actually domain-dependent, you do not round the same way in engineering applications than in banking applications (where fair rounding comes from), for example.  It is definitely not unusual to have to write your own rounding functions.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't one that behave the same as `std::round`.

However, there are also [`std::chrono::ceil`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/ceil) and [`std::chrono::floor`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/floor) that you can play around with.

You can surely do your own rounding quickly with something like:

```
roundedTime = time % 500 ? chrono::round(time) : chrono::ceil(time)
```

or write your own from scratch:

```
roundedTime = time / 1000 + (time % 1000 >= 500 ? 1 : 0)
```

Note: they are just pseudocode because I don't remember the exact syntax for `std::chrono`.

Comment: [The other answer posted by Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64733133/12861639) actually had a better and simple algorithm, should check his answer.